# How do I use Moq and DbFunctions in unit tests to prevent a NotSupportedException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, dbfunctions

I'm currently attempting to run some unit tests on a query that is running through the Entity Framework. The query itself runs without any issues on the live version, but the unit tests are always failing.

I've narrowed this down to my usage of DbFunctions.TruncateTime, but I don't know of a way around this to get the unit tests to reflect what is happening on the live server.

Here is the method that I am using:

```
    public System.Data.DataTable GetLinkedUsers(int parentUserId)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.Date;

        var query = from up in DB.par_UserPlacement
                    where up.MentorId == mentorUserId
                        && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(up.StartDate)
                        && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(up.EndDate)
                    select new
                    {
                        up.UserPlacementId,
                        up.Users.UserId,
                        up.Users.FirstName,
                        up.Users.LastName,
                        up.Placements.PlacementId,
                        up.Placements.PlacementName,
                        up.StartDate,
                        up.EndDate,
                    };

        query = query.OrderBy(up => up.EndDate);

        return this.RunQueryToDataTable(query);
    }
```

If I comment out the lines with DbFunctions in, the tests all pass (except for the ones that are checking that only valid results for a given date are run).

Is there a way I can provide a mocked version of DbFunctions.TruncateTime to use in these tests? Essentially it should just be returning Datetime.Date, but that isn't available in EF queries.

**Edit:** Here's the test that's failing that uses the date check:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanOnlyGetCurrentLinkedUsers()
    {
        var up = new List<par_UserPlacement>
        {
            this.UserPlacementFactory(1, 2, 1), // Create a user placement that is current
            this.UserPlacementFactory(1, 3, 2, false) // Create a user placement that is not current
        }.AsQueryable();

        var set = DLTestHelper.GetMockSet<par_UserPlacement>(up);

        var context = DLTestHelper.Context;
        context.Setup(c => c.par_UserPlacement).Returns(set.Object);

        var getter = DLTestHelper.New<LinqUserGetLinkedUsersForParentUser>(context.Object);

        var output = getter.GetLinkedUsers(1);

        var users = new List<User>();
        output.ProcessDataTable((DataRow row) => students.Add(new UserStudent(row)));

        Assert.AreEqual(1, users.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, users[0].UserId);
    }
```

**Edit 2:** This is the message and debug trace from the test in question:

```
Test Result: Failed

Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<0>

Debug Trace: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities
```

From what I've read, this is because there isn't a LINQ to Entities implementation of this method that could be used in this place for the Unit Test, although there is on the live version (as it's querying an SQL server).

Comment: It would be really helpful to see your test? Or at least a test that is failing.

Comment: This is a dead end: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21163650/861716

Comment: I've added on the test that's failing. Thanks for the link Gert, in that case, how should I go about testing this method?

Comment: What error did you get after running this test?

Comment: If you have Visual Studio Ultimate then you can use Microsoft fakes and [shims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176(v=vs.110).aspx])

Comment: When it comes to EF queries I only do integration tests. A cunning test framework with mocks and all will never convince me that the query really works against a live database.

Comment: I am interested to know what you did in the end?

Comment: I had to leave this for the time being as some more pressing issues had been coming to light. As a temporary measure, I removed the TruncateTime all together which works in this case as the input should already be truncated when coming in and this was a fail-safe, but the solutions that I'm looking at now is either the one you linked regarding creating my own method that I can mock or using a shim as @qujck mentioned to do the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for all of the help everyone, I managed to track down a solution that worked for me after reading up on shims that qujck mentioned. After adding a fake assembly of EntityFramework, I was able to fix these tests by changing them to the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanOnlyGetCurrentLinkedUsers()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Fakes.ShimDbFunctions.TruncateTimeNullableOfDateTime =
            (DateTime? input) =>
            {
                return input.HasValue ? (DateTime?)input.Value.Date : null;
            };

        var up = new List<par_UserPlacement>
        {
            this.UserPlacementFactory(1, 2, 1), // Create a user placement that is current
            this.UserPlacementFactory(1, 3, 2, false) // Create a user placement that is not current
        }.AsQueryable();

        var set = DLTestHelper.GetMockSet<par_UserPlacement>(up);

        var context = DLTestHelper.Context;
        context.Setup(c => c.par_UserPlacement).Returns(set.Object);

        var getter = DLTestHelper.New<LinqUserGetLinkedUsersForParentUser>(context.Object);

        var output = getter.GetLinkedUsers(1);
    }

    var users = new List<User>();
    output.ProcessDataTable((DataRow row) => users.Add(new User(row)));

    Assert.AreEqual(1, users.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, users[0].UserId);
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, this appears to only be available in VS Enterprise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223899/ms-fakes-shims-with-vs2015-professional

Answer (score 39):

I know I'm late to the game, but a very simple fix is to write your own method which uses the DbFunction attribute. Then use that function instead of DbFunctions.TruncateTime.

```
[DbFunction("Edm", "TruncateTime")]
public static DateTime? TruncateTime(DateTime? dateValue)
{
    return dateValue?.Date;
}
```

Using this function will execute the EDM TruncateTime method when used by Linq to Entities and will run the provided code otherwise.

Comment: Certainly the simplest and quickest solution I've seen and got us round that annoying problem. Longer term we're thinking we might try Dapper instead of EF where possible because it is so much simpler (assuming we can with respect to required functionality).

Comment: @StevePettifer Do you know what constitutes a valid namespaceName?  I'm finding the msdn docs too vague. I've tried TruncateTime's namespace, my classes namespace, the examples namespace. None worked.

Comment: @JohnOsborne Same problem!  "Edm" is the namespace MS chose for various entity framework DB functions, although damned if I know what it stands for. This page for `DbFunctions` mentions EDM a lot but I still have no good explanation of exactly why that namespace works and how. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I added the method but left the DbFunctions.TruncateTime call in my LINQ -- that is why it wasn't working :) I'm calling my static method(with attributes) and it is working now.

Comment: @JohnOsborne Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees - we've all been there! glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @StevePettifer EDM stands for Entity Data Model. See the model-declared function section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/entity-data-model

Comment: @esteuart Nice, thanks for that. I couldn't be bothered to find out as I try to avoid using EF as much as possible!!

Comment: I turned this into an extension method on `DateTime` and `DateTime?`, it works nicely. Usage is like `var dateOnly = myDateTime.ToDateOnly();`

Comment: Better late than never! I'm surprised I hadn't hit this hurdle earlier with DbFunctions. I just implemented a DbFunctionsEx with the static POCO alternative methods tagged with the applicable DbFunction attribute and my unit tests were happy while my EF queries continued to work with the DbFunction.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it. Since **unit testing of business logic** is generally **encouraged**, and since it is **perfectly OK** for business logic to issue **LINQ queries against application data**, then it must be **perfectly OK to unit test** those LINQ queries.

Unfortunately, **DbFunctions** feature of **Entity Framework** kills our ability to unit test code that contains LINQ queries. Moreover, it is architecturally wrong to use **DbFunctions** in business logic, because it couples business logic layer to a specific persistence technology (which is a separate discussion).

Having said that, **our goal** is the ability to **run LINQ query** like this:

```
var orderIdsByDate = (
    from o in repo.Orders
    group o by o.PlacedAt.Date 
         // here we used DateTime.Date 
         // and **NOT** DbFunctions.TruncateTime
    into g
    orderby g.Key
    select new { Date = g.Key, OrderIds = g.Select(x => x.Id) });
```

In **unit test**, this will boil down to **LINQ-to-Objects** running against a plain array of entities arranged in advance (for example). In a real run, it must work against a **real `ObjectContext`** of Entity Framework.

Here is a **recipe of achieving it** - although, it requires a few steps of yours. I'm cutting down a real working example:

**Step 1.** Wrap `ObjectSet<T>` inside our own implementation of `IQueryable<T>` in order to provide our own intercepting wrapper of `IQueryProvider`.

```
public class EntityRepository<T> : IQueryable<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ObjectSet<T> _objectSet;
    private InterceptingQueryProvider _queryProvider = null;

    public EntityRepository<T>(ObjectSet<T> objectSet)
    {
        _objectSet = objectSet;
    }
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _objectSet.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _objectSet.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }
    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _objectSet.AsQueryable().ElementType; }
    }
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _objectSet.AsQueryable().Expression; }
    }
    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get
        {
            if ( _queryProvider == null )
            {
                _queryProvider = new InterceptingQueryProvider(_objectSet.AsQueryable().Provider);
            }
            return _queryProvider;
        }
    }

    // . . . . . you may want to include Insert(), Update(), and Delete() methods
}
```

**Step 2**. Implement the intercepting query provider, in my example it is a nested class inside `EntityRepository<T>`:

```
private class InterceptingQueryProvider : IQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider _actualQueryProvider;

    public InterceptingQueryProvider(IQueryProvider actualQueryProvider)
    {
        _actualQueryProvider = actualQueryProvider;
    }
    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        var specializedExpression = QueryExpressionSpecializer.Specialize(expression);
        return _actualQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(specializedExpression);
    }
    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        var specializedExpression = QueryExpressionSpecializer.Specialize(expression);
        return _actualQueryProvider.CreateQuery(specializedExpression);
    }
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _actualQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }
    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _actualQueryProvider.Execute(expression);
    }
}
```

**Step 3.** Finally, implement a helper class named `QueryExpressionSpecializer`, which would replace `DateTime.Date` with `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`.

```
public static class QueryExpressionSpecializer
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo _s_dbFunctions_TruncateTime_NullableOfDateTime = 
        GetMethodInfo<Expression<Func<DateTime?, DateTime?>>>(d => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d));

    private static readonly PropertyInfo _s_nullableOfDateTime_Value =
        GetPropertyInfo<Expression<Func<DateTime?, DateTime>>>(d => d.Value);

    public static Expression Specialize(Expression general)
    {
        var visitor = new SpecializingVisitor();
        return visitor.Visit(general);
    }
    private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<TLambda>(TLambda lambda) where TLambda : LambdaExpression
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression)lambda.Body).Method;
    }
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TLambda>(TLambda lambda) where TLambda : LambdaExpression
    {
        return (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)lambda.Body).Member;
    }

    private class SpecializingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if ( node.Expression.Type == typeof(DateTime?) && node.Member.Name == "Date" )
            {
                return Expression.Call(_s_dbFunctions_TruncateTime_NullableOfDateTime, node.Expression);
            }

            if ( node.Expression.Type == typeof(DateTime) && node.Member.Name == "Date" )
            {
                return Expression.Property(
                    Expression.Call(
                        _s_dbFunctions_TruncateTime_NullableOfDateTime, 
                        Expression.Convert(
                            node.Expression, 
                            typeof(DateTime?)
                        )
                    ),
                    _s_nullableOfDateTime_Value
                );
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the above implementation of `QueryExpressionSpecializer` can be generalized to allow plugging in any number of additional conversions, allowing members of custom types to be used in LINQ queries, even though they are not known to Entity Framework.

Comment: It is not perfectly OK to unit test this way as effects on connecting to a real DB cannot be replicated with this approach. There are lot of limitations with this mocking approach and hence connecting to DB (recreating/seeding DB) is the perfectly OK approach.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14975425/1509728

To be honest, upon thinking about it I totally agree with the answer and generally follow the principle that my EF queries are tested against the database and only my application code is tested with Moq.

It looks like there is no elegant solution to using Moq for testing EF queries with your query above, while there are some hacky ideas out there.  For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300685/1509728) and the answer that follows it.  Both seem like they could work for you.

Another approach to testing your queries would be one implemented on another project I worked on:  Using VS out of box unit tests, each query (again refactored into its own method) test would be wrapped in a transaction scope.  Then the project's test framework would take care of manually entering phony data into the db and the query would try to filter this phony data.  At the end, the transaction is never completed so it is rolled back.  **Due to the nature of transaction scopes, this might not be an ideal scenario for a lot of projects.**  Most probably not on prod environments.

Otherwise if you must continue mocking functionality, you might want to consider other mocking frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure but couldn't you do something like this?

```
context.Setup(s => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
    .Returns<DateTime?>(new Func<DateTime?,DateTime?>(
        (x) => {
            /*  whatever modification is required here */
            return x; //or return modified;
        }));
```

Comment: I gave it a go, but unfortunately I can't add this as DbFunctions isn't part of the mocked object. The only difference I made to your recommendation was to add the mock to the DataContext (which is what is being mocked here with Moq), the getter object is not a mocked object as that's what I'm checking the  functionality of.

Comment: Ah!  My bad, Thanks!  Updated my code.  Let me think about this for a bit.

Answer (score -1):

since i hit the same problem recently, and opted for a simpler solution, wanted to post it here.. this solution requires no Shims, Mocking, nothing expansive etc.

1. Pass a 'useDbFunctions' boolean flag to your method with default value as true.
2. When your live code executes, your query will use DbFunctions and everything will work. Due to the default value, callers need not worry about it.
3. When your unit tests invoke the method to test, they can pass useDbFunctions: false.
4. In your method, you can make use the flag to compose your IQueryable..
   if useDbFunctions is true, use the DbFunctions to add the predicate to the queryable.
   if useDbFunctions is false, then skip the DbFunctions method call, and do an explicit C# equivalent solution.

This way, your unit tests will check almost 95% of your method in parity with live code. You still have the delta of "DbFunctions" vs. your equivalent code, but be diligent about it and the 95% will look like a lot of gain.

```
public System.Data.DataTable GetLinkedUsers(int parentUserId, bool useDbFunctions = true)
{
    var today = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var queryable = from up in DB.par_UserPlacement
                where up.MentorId == mentorUserId;

    if (useDbFunctions) // use the DbFunctions
    {
     queryable = queryable.Where(up => 
     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(up.StartDate)
     && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(today) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(up.EndDate));
    }  
    else
    {
      // do db-functions equivalent here using C# logic
      // this is what the unit test path will invoke
      queryable = queryable.Where(up => up.StartDate < today);
    }                    

    var query = from up in queryable
                select new
                {
                    up.UserPlacementId,
                    up.Users.UserId,
                    up.Users.FirstName,
                    up.Users.LastName,
                    up.Placements.PlacementId,
                    up.Placements.PlacementName,
                    up.StartDate,
                    up.EndDate,
                };

    query = query.OrderBy(up => up.EndDate);

    return this.RunQueryToDataTable(query);
}
```

Unit tests will invoke the mthod as:

```
GetLinkedUsers(parentUserId: 10, useDbFunctions: false);
```

Because unit tests would have setup local DbContext entities, the C# logic/DateTime functions would work.

Answer (score -10):

Use of Mocks ended sometime ago. Do not Mock, just connect to real DB. Regenerate/Seed DB on start of test. 
If you still want to go ahead with mocks then create your own method as given below. IT changes behaviour runtime. When using real DB it uses DB functions, else this method. Replace DBfunctions method in code with this method

```
public static class CanTestDbFunctions
{
    [System.Data.Entity.DbFunction("Edm", "TruncateTime")]
    public static DateTime? TruncateTime(DateTime? dateValue)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

[This is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596(v=vs.110).aspx) the real function that is called. And remember, time cannot be removed from DateTime object, live with midnight or create a string equivalent.

Comment: Some databases are too large and complex to reseed for every unit test. I don't know where you get the idea that "Use of Mocks ended sometime ago". That is a ridiculous statement.

Comment: reseed is complex for a single test.(every test or single test does not matter) . Using mocks speeds development in the beginning. You may use them if you are starting development on a new framework. But the statement above is intended for those who have tried unit testing(short tests) for years and moved to integration tests(long tests).. and then just integration tests as the value(return on investment) is more. For some seeding is complex and risky they dont do it. Some go for it ..this is for those.

Comment: If your "unit" tests connect to a database: They are _not_ "unit" tests

Comment: @Eregrith yes they are integration tests. The question states: "unit tests on a query that is running through the Entity Framework".  Do we really need to do a unit test here?

Comment: What should be unit tested is the logic of the querying. Also "Use of mocks ended sometime ago"... What?

Comment: Integration test is best suited in this scenario hence the answer. But if you could provide an example of what this logic testing is , it would be helpful

Comment: Also please refer @felix-b answer

Comment: and about mocks ending this should help https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/before-you-feed-unit-test-beast-s-a-n-j-ay-mohan/?trackingId=5eIFIJGSBpnGuXMEz2PnwQ%3D%3D