# Fake DbFunctions DiffDays

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to fake DbFunctions.DiffDays but am encountering some difficulty. The signatures seem to match but I am still getting

> "The type or namespace name 'Fakes' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity'"

My code is as follows:

```
System.Data.Entity.Fakes.ShimDbFunctions.DiffDaysNullableOfDateTimeNullableOfDateTime = 
    (DateTime? d1, DateTime? d2) =>
    {
        var timespan = d1.Value - d2.Value;
        return (int?)Convert.ToInt32(timespan.TotalDays);
    };
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in : [Moq and DbFunctions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407748/moq-and-dbfunctions)

Basically you need to add `Fakes` to `EntityFramework`.