# MS Fakes/Shims with VS2015 professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, microsoft-fakes, shim

I am working for a client on a project and existing code/tests are using MS Fakes library and Shims to isolate tests etc...

I installed VS 2015 enterprise edition, on a trial, and all was fine. With my MSDN subscription I get up to VS 2015 Professional and now tests don't run, get failure:

```
Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.

    at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.ResolveProfilerPath()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create()
```

Looking at it the shims is trying to use Intellitrace, which VS2015 doesn't give me. Anyone know a way around this, other than purchasing Enterprise edition of VS?

Answer (score 27):

Never mind, just checked on MS and looks like Fakes is only available for Enterprise edition devs.... :(

[VS Comparisons](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx)

Comment: Appreciated. Cheers :)